# Framer motion keyframe animations with clip-path. Only second part has the duration and ease i want

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I fire the following code when the users starts scrolling. I cannot figure out how to make the clip-path array to be smooth and have correct ease values and duration.

```
 await animate('#intro_image_wrapper_2', {
        clipPath: ["inset(40% 0 40% 44%)",  "inset(40% 10% 40% 44%)"],
    },
    {
      ease: 'easeInOut',
      duration: 4,
      // times: [0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75 ]
    })
```

I have tried playing around with a lot of values and different stuff, but I cannot figure it out.